# Activity with Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (android)

Tags: android

I have stack of activities launched after one another.
but in one of the activity I need to launch that particular activity with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

So that it will finish all the previous activities and start.

Problem I am facing that i don't want to finish one of the activity from the stack it should be presence on back of the newly launched activity.

Suppose I have activities `[A] [B] [C] [D]`
I am starting `[D]` activity with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` after starting activity `[D]` it will destroy all the activities, I want activity `[B]` to be kept running on the back and when we press back key on `[D]` it should display activity `[B]`.

How to do this?

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Mudassir said, start activity [A]. When you call [B] simply use the FLAG to clear all data but [B], and then you can call [D] without flag from [B];thus having [B][D] like you wanted? Then on back button press you will go from [D] to [B], without having any other data?. You seem to not be thinking he wants you to call [B] with flag from [D], and what would the purpose of that be? You'd wind up with just [B] at that point.

-Either way, you lose [C] along the way. A solution might be:

```
startActivity(A)
[in activity A] startActivity(B) - WITH CLEAR_TOP TO KILL [A]
[in activity B] startActivityForResult(C) - WHEN [C] IS finish() IT WILL COME BACK TO [B]
[in activity B, onActivityResult()] startActivity(D)
```

This will give you JUST [B]&[D] while still getting to [C]....try it, it will work.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to call Activity `[B]` with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, this will destroy all activities but `[B]`. After that, call Activity `[D]`.

Comment: I want to call Activity D with flag clear top. not activity B

Comment: @PP: I said call Activity B (no matter if its already running) with Flag, this will make sure that the Activity B is at the top, then call Activity D.

Comment: So you are saying that is activity B is running and at the time of running activity D i have to again startActivity B with flag Clear top and than after startActivity() D with flag clear top. ... is it right?

Comment: Yeah, but start Activity D without FLAG_CLEAR_TOP, else it will clears the Activity B. Give it a try.

Comment: launching Activity D with flag clear top, will clear Activity B. not worth giving a try.

Comment: PP you aren't paying attention.