# Android:Delete a activity in backstack

Tags: android

I have got 4 activity let it be A->B->C->D.In every A,B,C activity user need to enter data all data will sent to server in C activity  if the user data is correct he will move on to D activity and all the activity A,B,C removed from stack.If the data is in correct i need give the user to reenter data i.e is on back press it has to move C->B->A.My question is How to remove A,B,C activity when user enter D activity.

Answer (score 5):

Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` this shall solve your problem

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
> current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
> activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
> this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
> new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
> If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
> component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
> the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Use it like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
        yourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
```

and also, take a look at this question:

[Activity with Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179041/activity-with-flag-flag-activity-clear-top-android)

Edit : I thought you want to move to your home activity from D and want to remove all activities from stack

Your stack would be like homeactivity , A , B , C , D
so i gave you this solution as this shall remove all activities in stack on top of your home activity.

If you want to clear the the stack while going to D, for that you can use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME) or [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

But both of these for api level 11.

Comment: How can i use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when the D activity is at top of the stack and A,B,C are at the bottom of the stack

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer interesting for me also, but I can offer a solution:
For example you start activity A from O:  O->A->B->C->D.
On activity O you can put in android manifest `android:launchMode="singleTop"`
Then, when data are ok, you can start activity O with flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" - it remove from stack A,B,C and will be called method `onNewIntent (Intent intent)` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent) in O, where you can start activity D.

Comment: I think your idea will work but i don't want to move backward i.e to O activity to clear the back stack.Is there any better idea?

Comment: Another idea: use `startActivityForResult()` in every activity A,B,C and `onResult` call finish()

Answer (score 0):

You can start activities with startActivityForResult, and call setResult from for example activity D, in C activity you can listen activity result, and related of this result finish activity or not, or call setResalt from C activity ...

Comment: OK,C will be removed but what about A and B when user in D activity press back button it will go through B->A

Comment: no if you call setResult from C and in B onActivityResult call setResult and finish() and in A call finish().

Answer (score 0):

When you want to move D activity there you need to check your
conditions and if your condition is satisfied then you need to enter
into your Next activity(i.e., D) .In that case you need to use the
following code..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,D.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Suppose In on backpress you need to use finish(). to move back i.e., C
-> B -> A.

Comment: When the user enters to D activity (i.e if condition satisfies)  i don't want A,B,C activity to be in stack

Comment: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); this line will clear all of stack.for [more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Comment: I tried, it seems like FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, which doesn't exist in Android 2.2 SDK's.

Comment: You can try FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET  with this flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code with some modifications:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try looking for Activity's public method startActivity(Intent i) and finish() [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

In usage wise, it should look like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: This does not answer the question.