# Prevent going to parent activity if child has finished

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have some kind of a login activity which returns to main if login successfull. But after that, if user presses hardware "back" button, main activity is restarting for some reason... 
It seems like it is going to previous (login) activity, but since it has already finished, parent activity is restarted. 
I have tried using `<activity android:noHistory="true">` on login activity in manifest. `startActivityForResult()` is not a solution for me as well. Problem remains.
Can you help me with any other ideas?
UPD: I am calling finish() when going back to main activity

Comment: Do you Override `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: Use startActivity() in the Login Activity to start the new Activity, then call finish() in the Login Activity to kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by forcely exiting the whole application in main activity's `onBackPressed()` method. Although, it doesn't seem like a clear solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you haven't finished your activity when you're 'returning' to main. Check where you create your intents, always finish activities you do *not* want to be accessed via the back stack.

Comment: I'm already calling finish() on a login activity after it starts main, so it is not a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

try use this after each startActivity()

```
startActivity(intent);//you already have this
finish();//add just this .. and report
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `finish()` inside of `onBackPressed()` method. Android / OS will do it for you automatically.

Call `finish()` only If login was ok and you want to close the login activity. Of course only if main activity present in the back stack.

If back stack contains no main activity, so open it by using of common `startActivity` method. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12777105/1614378) to remove an activity from the back stack.